# iCarousel USING_CHAMELEON issue or NSRUNLOOP

Tags: iphone, objective-c, carousel, nsrunloop

I need to use iCarousel Carousel of type `iCarouselTypeRotary`

I am currently using the carousel downloaded from the below link:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/create-an-awesome-carousel-version-2-0/?search_index=2

It works on all simulators except on iPhone 4 inch 64 bit stimulator
It crashes on line:

```
[timer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

The above line in written in `iCarousel.m` `startAnimation` function
It somehow goes in:

```
#ifdef ICAROUSEL_IOS
#ifndef USING_CHAMELEON

        //support for Chameleon
        timer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(step)];
        [timer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
#endif
```

I have not done anything to use ***CHAMELEON***.

Please help me to solve crash.

I then tried downloading the carousel files from:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

but somehow I am not able to do click with large width in `iCarouselTypeRotary` so I had to use from the mobile tut plus only, but in that it is crashing in iPhone retina 4 inch 64 bit simulator.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who ever faces the problem:

Sometimes the timer was not getting allocated
in **carousel.m** file the property was written as:

```
@property (nonatomic, __unsafe_unretained)
```

We changed it to:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)
```

Also even after assigning it on previous line we check if timer is present 
if present then only we do `addToRunLoop` method.

Now it is working.